# Problematic CSS transition based on em units

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, font-size

I'm trying to create an effect where an anchor element that's located in header scales itself up on hovering while maintaining the width and height of an element so that it fits the header and doesn't move or affect other elements in any way.
Animations are working great in Chrome but in Mozilla, Firefox and Edge/IE the transitions don't work well at all.

- The header has a height of 4em.
- Default font size for anchor elements    that are to be animated is
  2em. Width and height are also 2em (2*2 = 4em so I get the perfect
  squares that fit the header).
- When hovering i change the font-size to 2.5em and both width and height to 1.6em (2.5*1.6 = 4em of the header height) <- I think that this is a problem.

I tried animating only height, font-size and line-height but that doesn't eliminate the problem. It seems that browsers are confused by the width and height being defined by em units so they scale down the content first and than scale it up. Still, that behavior isn't present in Chrome where everything works just fine.

Is there any solution for this problem as I would like to avoid using px units because of the easier implementation of responsiveness of the website. Or maybe I should switch to using px units and use more media queries for the site?

Problematic code:

```
<!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <nav class="nav-buttons">
                <a href="#">L1</a>
                <a href="#">L2</a>
                <a href="#">L3</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

/* global element settings */
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* navigation buttons */

.nav-buttons > *,
.nav-buttons > *:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  /*text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em #555555;*/
  transition-property: height, line-height, font-size, text-align, vertical-align;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.nav-buttons > *:hover,
.nav-buttons > *:active,
.button-active {
  transition-property: height, line-height, font-size, text-align, vertical-align;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
}
```

Accompanying JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2futafsw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the browsers are simply handling the transitions differently. What you need to do is append the browser prefixes to the `transition-property` rules and apply the styles accordingly.

For FireFox, that's `-moz-transition-property`, Chrome / Safari is `-webkit-transition-property`.

I've simplified your transitions a bit. Chrome works fine with just the font size, and FireFox needs an animation on the margins (which, funny enough, mess up the Chrome animations).

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

/* global element settings */
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-buttons > a,
.nav-buttons > a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  -moz-transition-property: font-size, margin;
  -webkit-transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.nav-buttons > a:hover,
.nav-buttons > a:active,
.button-active {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: -.20em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header" class="">
  <nav class="nav-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">a</a>
    <a href="#">L1</a>
    <a href="#">L2</a>
    <a href="#">L3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you are basically suggesting me to try and use negative margins to negate the scaling of the whole element while hovering?

Comment: For FireFox, yes. That'll cause issues in Chrome. You've gotta either do them individually using CSS transitions (`-moz`, `-webkit`, `-ms`, etc), or use CSS transforms like @Quoid has in his answer.

Comment: After experimenting with your solution I've found out that it's not working with IE nor Edge. I've tried with and without prefixes and with and without margin transitioning.
Looks like I'll possibly have to switch to transforms or avoid animating anything in IE/Edge alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest accomplishing the same goal, but using a different approach. I would use the `transform` property. It is less code, accomplishes the same effect and is generally [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/opqnmfza/4/)**

For your particular issue, it seemed to me that the `font-size` transition was firing late for some reason on `moz`; I was unable to figured out why.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

nav a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">L1</a>
    <a href="#">L2</a>
    <a href="#">L3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I've actually noticed some text aliasing problems (text becomes a bit blurry on the edges) when using this method so I prefer avoiding it unless I really need to use it.
Edit: Well, I've noticed it in webkit browsers and didn't bother to test in in others.

Comment: This is neat. I noticed the blur too, but I thought it was just me since I'm not wearing my glasses. Any way to do this _and_ get rid of the blur?

Comment: There are actually some suggestions here:
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/transforms-cause-font-smoothing-weirdness-in-webkit/
Although there are many solutions that sometimes work and sometimes don't but not a definite one.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun you can get rid of the blur, this was just a quick example to show you a *"better"* alternative. Just start with the elements already scaled; will take tweaking - **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/opqnmfza/4/)**

Comment: That's a nice workaround. However I've compared your previous demo with the new one and there's basically no difference in the aliasing in Chrome.
Transforms are pretty nice but transitions will have to work for me this time as I've been using them for some other animation system which is very much dependant on this one and it would be painful to switch over to the transforms right now.
But your answer has provided a very neat solution.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandarBencun. Please be aware, that my examples are using `transition` as well (as the animating "force"); the `property` I am transitioning, *is* the `transform` property. It's easy to get these two property confused, but that are not mutually exclusive or anything. `transform` is like any other css property.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but I am aware of that already.
In the end it looks like I'll have to go with the transform property as width/height transitioning is giving me headaches in IE and Edge.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun glad to help:)